# Rails AJAX 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm completing a tutorial on Rails - however the tutorial was written with Rails 2, and as I have Rails 3 I'm having to convert everything over.

I've got a Google Map, and when you click on it, you should have a pop-up appear with a new marker and a form for entering the data into. When I click the map, the marker is appearing, but no form for entering data. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm guessing it has something to do with the ajax?? When I click anywhere on the map to try and enter new data, the web console is giving me a 500 internal server error. No idea where I'm going wrong!

Here's the controller code for the 'new' action:

```
def new
  @incident = Incident.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      @incident.latitude=params['latitude']
      @incident.longitude=params['longitude']
      render :partial=>'new', :locals=>{:incident=>@incident}
    }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @incident }
  end
end
```

The index view:

```
<h1>Listing incidents</h1>

<%= render(:partial=>"map", :locals=>{:data=>"/incidents.xml",
  :full_page=>true, :show_action=>'show', :new_action=>'new'}) %>
```

And the 'new' partial:

```
<h1>New incident</h1>
<% form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info'), :remote => true do |f| %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :mountain %> <%= f.text_field :mountain %>
 </p>
 <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :when %> <%= f.datetime_select :when %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :title %> <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :description %><br/>
   <%= f.text_area :description, :rows=>3 %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= f.submit "Create" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Here's the stack trace (when I load the page, then click on the map for a new incident):

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 14:35:18
 +0100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (173ms)
[2012-09-27 14:35:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/prototype.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 14:35:18 +
0100
Served asset /prototype.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-09-27 14:35:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/incidents.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 14:35:19 +0100
Processing by IncidentsController#index as XML
  ←[1m←[35mIncident Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "incidents".* FROM "incidents"
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 945ms (Views: 184.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
[2012-09-27 14:35:20] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/incidents/new?latitude=42.50990089326676&longitude=-99.4921875" fo
r 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 14:35:43 +0100
Processing by IncidentsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"latitude"=>"42.50990089326676", "longitude"=>"-99.4921875"}
ERROR: compiling _app_views_incidents__new_html_erb___613446974_25808988 RAISED
c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/views/incidents/_new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpect
ed ',', expecting keyword_end
'); form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info'), :remote => true do |f|
                                            ^
c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/views/incidents/_new.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpec
ted keyword_ensure, expecting $end
Function body:           def _app_views_incidents__new_html_erb___613446974_2580
8988(local_assigns, output_buffer)
            _old_virtual_path, @virtual_path = @virtual_path, "incidents/_new";_
old_output_buffer = @output_buffer;incident = local_assigns[:incident];new = loc
al_assigns[:new];;@output_buffer = output_buffer || ActionView::OutputBuffer.new
;@output_buffer.safe_concat('<h1>New incident</h1>
'); form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info'), :remote => true do |f|
@output_buffer.safe_concat(' <p>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.label :mountain );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
 ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.text_field :mountain );@output_buffer.safe_concat
('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  </p>
  ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.hidden_field :latitude );@output_buffer.safe_con
cat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.hidden_field :lon
gitude );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  <p>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.label :when );@output_buffer.safe_concat(' ');
@output_buffer.append= ( f.datetime_select :when );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  </p>
  <p>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.label :title );@output_buffer.safe_concat(' ')
;@output_buffer.append= ( f.text_field :title );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  </p>
  <p>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.label :description );@output_buffer.safe_conca
t('<br/>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.text_area :description, :rows=>3 );@output_buf
fer.safe_concat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  </p>
  <p>
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( f.submit "Create" );@output_buffer.safe_concat('

');@output_buffer.safe_concat('  </p>
'); end
@output_buffer.to_s
          ensure
            @virtual_path, @output_buffer = _old_virtual_path, _old_output_buffe
r
          end

Backtrace: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_v
iew/template.rb:297:in `module_eval'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/templat
e.rb:297:in `compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/templat
e.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/templat
e.rb:232:in `compile!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/templat
e.rb:144:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/templat
e.rb:143:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_view/rendere
r/renderer.rb:15:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
ore_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
ore_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_record/rai
lties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:24:in `block (2 lev
els) in new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:20:in `new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:414:in `_run__322942522__process_action__447782570__callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/n
otifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_record/rai
lties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/base.rb:121:in `process'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/abstract_controller
/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_controller/m
etal.rb:246:in `block in action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/rou
ting/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/rou
ting/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/rou
ting/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `b
lock in call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `e
ach'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `c
all'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/rou
ting/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in
`call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/flash.rb:238:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:2
05:in `context'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:2
00:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_record/que
ry_cache.rb:64:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_record/con
nection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:405:in `_run__711941801__call__927210605__callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
allbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.4.rc1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:
26:in `call_app'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.4.rc1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:
16:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
`call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.4.rc1/lib/active_support/c
ache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/mid
dleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.4.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:i
n `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.4.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:
220:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in
`call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.4.rc1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer
.rb:17:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in
 `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
  Rendered incidents/_new.html.erb (169.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 178ms

ActionView::Template::Error (c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/views/incidents/_new.html.
erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
'); form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info'), :remote => true do |f|
                                            ^
c:/Ruby193/incidents/app/views/incidents/_new.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpec
ted keyword_ensure, expecting $end):
    1: <h1>New incident</h1>
    2: <% form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info'), :remote => true do |f| %>
    3:  <p>
    4:     <%= f.label :mountain %> <%= f.text_field :mountain %>
    5:   </p>
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in new'
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:20:in `new'


  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_d
ispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_d
ispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.4.rc1/lib/action_d
ispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (1
38.0ms)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're getting a HTTP 500 error on some Ajax call. Please post the actual error message from your logfiles along with a stacktrace.

Comment: Here's the error: [14:29:07.279] GET http://localhost:3000/incidents/new?latitude=51.98036694779745&longitude=-93.515625 [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error  322ms]

Comment: Please look in your Rails logfile ([RAILS_ROOT/log/development.log) for the exact error message and backtrace, and add it to your original question.

Comment: I've added it now. It does seem to have a problem with the ajax call, but I can't see where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Remove the `","` from in front of the `:remote => true` and behind the `form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info')` and try it again

Comment: I've tried that, still no better. The trace is now saying "unexpected ':', expecting keyword $end" (as in the colon before :remote). It also seems to have a problem with the 'new' partial, although there isn't a line 23, and that is the line it is complaining about!?

Comment: I'm guessing map_info is the name of your action? - Sorry stupid question, I forgot that you listed it. Give me a second and I'll write a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! map_info is the name of a div in the map partial. I've had no end of problems with this tutorial as it is written for rails 2... so I don't know if it is any other rails 2-specific syntax causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error:

Its the `","` from in front of the `:remote => true`, behind the `form_for(incident, :update=>'map_info')`. Remove it

Ok so lets recode it. Try:

```
<%= form_for incidents_url, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

You have to add a new file in incidents called `new.js.erb` (`incidents/new.js.erb`). Normally it would be called `create.js.erb`, but you're using the `new action`, not create.

Inside that file you write the jQuery code that updated the div.

```
$(".class_name_of_div").prepend("<%= @incident.which_ever_attribute_you_want %>");
```

Also you might want to change your controller a bit:

```
def new
  @incident = Incident.new
  @incident.latitude = params[:latitude]
  @incident.longitude = params[:longitude]
  @incident.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Change the partial too:

```
<%= render 'incidents/map', :incident => @incident %>
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I've tried that, it still doesn't work. It then complains about the colon at the front of ':remote'. It also seems to be giving errors for the 'new' partial, and the 'new' action in the controller, but seeing as this is the code that is given as the 'answer code' from the tutorial, I have no idea why it isn't working!!

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!! How would I edit that to include the :update=>'map_info'?

Comment: What do you want to do with map_info? -I've never used rails 2.. I can tell you how to do it in rails 3 :)

Comment: I'm using rails 3 - what I want to do is have the 'map_info' div update when the new incident is created - how would I do that (in an ajax-ish way)?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - it is almost now working, except it is now saying that no route matches [POST] for incidents#new, when I click submit for a new incident. I can't change the routes so that all requests for a new incident actually create one, so how do I get it to route to the create action when the submit button is clicked instead? I hate this tutorial, it leaves so much out!!

Comment: It should be routed. Have you got `resources :incidents` in your `config/routes` file? Sorry I took a little longer, I had to step out momentarily.

Comment: sorry I had to go too!! Still not fixed, bit of a head-scratcher. Yes, it does have resources :incidents - it was a scaffolded project so no idea why it's not working! Will have to keep trying but am running out of ideas!! Thanks for all your help - you solved the original problem so will mark as answered :)

Comment: oh great thanks. I'll help you until it works. Go into `config/routes` and find anything that mentions incidents. It should say `resources :incidents`. If it doesn't, try adding the line `match "/incidents", :to => "incidents#new"`